# Importing FacebookSDK to Unity Android project causes build to crash

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have a simple 2d mobile game that I'm working on and it was made in Unity. I want to have an option to share info on Facebook, however, when I add the FacebookSDK to the project, even if I'm not even using anything from it besides the Facebook Settings, the project's build stops working and crashes whenever I try to open it.

I checked the problem and it seems to be something related to the FacebookContentProvider, since I had this error showing up in my log:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: ...`

Did anyone have problems with this kind of thing before? I tried changing the AndroidManifest file and play a little with some of the settings in the Facebook Developer's page but nothing seems to work.

I'm using Unity 2019.1.14f1 and FacebookSDK 7.17.2, but I also tried with different versions of the FacebookSDK (7.15.1 and 7.16.1), but got the same problem.